# Slick JS Vertical Scrolling Continuos, but cannot be drag/touch swipe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slick.js, vertical-scrolling

I want to create a smooth continuos vertical slider with a swiping/touch enabled.

I'm trying to create a vertical slider to show my product's item, i have managed to do that with slick with the property of "vertical" and "verticalSwiping", but when I added the continuos settings ( speed, cssEase, etc ) from what I gather in slick github issue pages.... The slider can't seems to be swiped correctly.

Here is my codepen: https://codepen.io/DilrajPutra10/pen/bPvQmM

```
$('.slick-carousel').slick({
        vertical:true,
        verticalSwiping:true,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 0,
        speed:9000,
        cssEase: 'linear',
        infinite: true,
        arrows:false,
  });
```

Comment: I increased the speed to 15000. looks like its working..!

Comment: @Coder It does works at the first time, but as the product goes up the swipe dont work until it changes with the previous item positions.